# F# not understanding TCP cancellation

Tags: f#

I have a NET 7 application, which runs as a Windows service, and starts a HostedService which instantiates one or more instances of a TCP handling class based on end user configuration.  A requirement is to be able to start a new instance of the TCP handler or stop a running instance based on end user updates without the need to restart the service manually.  No problem starting a new instance to listen on a different port but I have been unsuccessful in trying to terminate a running instance.  I pass in a unique CancellationToken from instantiating a CancellationTokenSource object, which I then save along w/ the port #. When the code detects that a port should no longer be listened on it tries to terminate the TCPListener.  However, despite reading many different articles and trying multiple approaches, the cancellation never takes effect.

Would greatly appreciate someone pointing out my error here.

Code that creates the token and starts the TCPListener:

```
let tokenSouce = new CancellationTokenSource ()
let handler = new ScannerController (tokenSouce.Token)
handler.StartListening port
ScannerInstances.Add (new ScannerInstance (port, tokenSouce, tokenSouce.Token))
```

Partial class implementation:

```
type ScannerController (portToken : CancellationToken) = 
    let mutable server : TcpListener = null
    let mutable portId = 0
    let mutable errorMessage = String.Empty
    
    member this.StartListeningOnPort portNumber =
        try
            server <- new TcpListener (new IPEndPoint (IPAddress.Any, portNumber))
            portId <- portNumber
            server.Start ()
            portToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested ()
            //
            //  Define a recursive asynchronous function to accept new TCP connections.
            //
            let rec connectLoop () = 
                async { 
                    let! ct = Async.CancellationToken
                    while not ct.IsCancellationRequested do
                        let! client = server.AcceptTcpClientAsync () |> Async.AwaitTask
                        this.processMessage client portToken |> Async.Start
                        return! connectLoop ()
                }
            let worker = Async.TryCancelled (connectLoop (), fun f -> server.Stop ())
            Async.Start (worker, portToken)
            
        with | :? SocketException as ex -> 
                if  ex.SocketErrorCode = SocketError.AddressAlreadyInUse then
                    errorMessage <- $"TCP/IP port number {portId} is already in use."
                else
                    errorMessage <- $"Error {ex.Message} trying to listen on TCP port: {portId}"
             | _ as ex -> 
                 errorMessage <- $"StartListening on port: {portId} encountered a fatal exception.{FormatExceptionMessage ex}"
```

Code to set the token:

```
let cancelToken (scanner : ScannerInstance) =
scanner.TokenSource.Cancel ()
ScannerInstances.Remove scanner |> ignore
```

Comment: Do you mean that the server.Stop is never hit? If that's the case, I am not surprised that attempts to reuse the port are blocked.

Comment: If you want to skip all the hassle of TCP/UDP server/client programming in .NET, there's this open source free library - Gemstone.Communication - that I very strongly recommend. It's dirt simple, and won't give you one surprise after another like the one you're struggling with now. I know because I've been using it for ten or maybe fifteen years on maybe a hundred cases.

Comment: Running netstat -aon shows the app is still listening on the port.

Comment: Frequent problem, and I see two possibilities. You need to make sure you've properly closed down the connection to any clients, and also the listening port. Also dispose disposable resources. Number two, even with that out of the way, it may take some time for communication resources to be released behind the scenes, so you should repeatedly try to reconnect for a while. I'm on F# Slack.

Comment: It probably happens because you don't pass cancellation token into `server.AcceptTcpClientAsync ()`. One important difference between F#'s async and dotnet's tasks is that cancellation tokens are not implicitly passed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tutorials/async#core-concepts, more on cancellation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tutorials/async#core-concepts